# Bad Windows Authentication sign on

Tags: sql-server, windows

I do not have install privileges on my machine.

Another user who has admin privileges installed it, but told the system to use Windows Authentication for the sign on.

Is there a way they can change the User Instances from one Windows Authentication to another without having to reinstall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Someone who has administrative rights (aka admin rights) to the SQL instance can change this by using SQL Server Management Studio.